# JSONArray.add(JSONObject) in for loop is replacing old values in for loop and Array consists of the last values in the loop

Tags: java, arrays, json, api

Hi Below is a simple method which I am using to dynamically generate the JSON request based on Array length from some other API response.

However inside the for loop everything seems to work fine except at the end when JSONArray.add is called, it replaces old jsonObject values inside the array to a new one, and at the end whole array consists of the only same set of JSON objects.
After a lot of debugging can't find the solution, is due to a variable declaration or something. Below is the method I am using

For ref: I am using minidev.JSON

```
public JSONObject method1(JSONObject sampleJsonObjTemplate, String responseofotherapi) {

    JSONArray jsonArray = JsonPath.parse(responseofotherapi).read("$.columns");
    JSONArray dataSetColumnArray = new JSONArray();

    JSONArray currentJsonColumnArr= JsonPath.parse(dataSetObj).read("$.columns");
    JSONObject currentJsonColumnObject= (JSONObject) currentJsonColumnArr.get(0);

    LinkedHashMap<String,Object> currentColumn;

    for(int columnNumber = 0; columnNumber < jsonArray.size(); columnNumber++){

        currentColumn= (LinkedHashMap<String,Object>)jsonArray.get(columnNumber);
        String name = currentColumn.get("name").toString();
        currentJsonColumnObject.put("name",name);
        currentJsonColumnObject.put("alias",name+" Column Alias ");
        currentJsonColumnObject.put("description",name+" Column Description ");

        dataSetColumnArray.add(columnNumber,currentJsonColumnObject);

        currentColumn.clear();

    }

    JSONObject updatedDataSetReq=JsonPath.parse(dataSetObj).set("$.columns",dataSetColumnArray).json();

    return updatedDataSetReq;
}
```

Comment: `put()` will add a key/value pair in the JSONObject so your code is modifying current object before you add.

Comment: Hi Karan, 

Thanks for looking into it, 
Though before another loops starts I am adding that Jsonobject to the JsonArray, 
and then reusing the JsonObject for another set of values,
It was intentional so for each loop there will be a json object and it will end that in JsonArray before loop finishes.

Comment: You can debug and check what values are being added to your arrays.

Comment: Already tried that many times, and thats the problem, 
the json object on each iteration has different values taken from hashmap: 
"currentColumn= (LinkedHashMap<String,Object>)jsonArray.get(columnNumber);"

But when dataSetColumnArray.add(columnNumber,currentJsonColumnObject);
Get called it not only adds the current json object but the previous jsonobject values also changes.

So the Array now has two elements(JsonObjects) with same values (later one)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `currentJsonColumnObject` object assigning in `for` loop.

you are using the same object `currentJsonColumnObject` for all iterations which is referring to `currentJsonColumnArr.get(0)`.

To solve your issue you need to set a different object for `currentJsonColumnObject`.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = JsonPath.parse(responseofotherapi).read("$.columns");
JSONArray dataSetColumnArray = new JSONArray();

JSONArray currentJsonColumnArr= JsonPath.parse(dataSetObj).read("$.columns");
//object will be set inside loop
JSONObject currentJsonColumnObject;

LinkedHashMap<String,Object> currentColumn;

for(int columnNumber = 0; columnNumber < jsonArray.size(); columnNumber++){

    currentColumn= (LinkedHashMap<String,Object>)jsonArray.get(columnNumber);

    // getting object from `currentJsonColumnArr` instead of using the same.
    currentJsonColumnObject= (JSONObject) currentJsonColumnArr.get(columnNumber);

    String name = currentColumn.get("name").toString();
    currentJsonColumnObject.put("name",name);
    currentJsonColumnObject.put("alias",name+" Column Alias ");
    currentJsonColumnObject.put("description",name+" Column Description ");

    dataSetColumnArray.add(columnNumber,currentJsonColumnObject);

    currentColumn.clear();

}
```